# Magento top nevigation bar different colors for categories

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I make one of the categories in the top nevigation bar in differnt color then rest of the categories?
For instens- SALE category

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1, the easiest**

You can use the category class, if you are getting classes by default in your template ( `echo $this->getBodyClasses()` )

In this case you should use **.category-sales** selector in your package css
. An example for background red:

```
body.category-sales .links ul li {
 background:red;
}
```

**Method 2**

...Other way could be adding a custom.css by layout

In this case you need create a file beyond skin/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/css/category-sales.css

And adding this file only for an specific category id

```
  <CATEGORY_"your category id">
    <reference name="head">
       <action method="addItem">
          <type>skin_css</type>
          <name>css/category-sales.css</name>
       </action>
     </reference>
   </CATEGORY_"your category id">
```

**Edit** this layout update should be in your *local.xml*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In the second case, what should I put in the category-sales.css file?

Comment: Every css you need override for this category... for a simple background in your top links...
.links ul li { background: red; }